# Django: Failure to render Request Context

Tags: django, requestcontext

I have this in my views.py:

```
def announcements(request):
    return render_to_response('events.html', {
        'posts1': Blog.objects.filter(category__title="Announcements")
         }, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

And this in my base.html:

```
{{ posts1 }}
```

But nothing from the above request context gets rendered when I  load the home page.

Edit 1:

It looks like I am on a wrong path here. My aim is to display the posts under "announcement" category throughout my website in a fixed sidebar. Whichever page is opened the sidebar in that page should contain only posts from "announcement" category. Any suggestion for how to achieve it?

Comment: Are you sure there are any blog items which match that category?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you could use HttpResponse.content to see the formatted page as a string.  Just something I've found useful in the past

Comment: I'd check to make sure your Blog query returns data, django debug toolbar would allow you to see all context values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [inclusion template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) and use it in templates where you want to display that sidebar.